# How to add filtering in REST JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, rest

i have a problem here, i want to filter my json with some condition (example : i want to search from nama that contain character L or V or i can search full name of the value). How can i do that?

this is the code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, COntent-Disposition,Content-Description');
require_once('helper_connect.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM product";
$sql = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query);
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    array_push($result, array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'kategori' => $row['kategori'],
        'nama' => $row['nama'],
        'deskripsi' => $row['deskripsi'],
        'berat' => $row['berat'],
        'harga' => $row['harga'],
        'gambar' => $row['gambar'],
        'stock' => $row['stock'],
        'attribut' => array(
            0 => array(
                'warna' => $row['warna'],
                'ukuran' => $row['ukuran'],
                'jenis_bahan' => $row['jenis_bahan'],
                'motif' => $row['motif'],
                'penutup' => $row['penutup']
                )
            )
        ));
    }
echo json_encode(array('product' => $result));
?>
```

Comment: i saw your code outputs `json`, are you trying to 1) filter for specific "nama" on `sql`; 2) filter the `$result` for specific "nama."

Comment: in that code im not adding the filtering at all because idk the code how to filter it. that code just make json from mysql using PHP

Comment: fyi, you can filter on `sql` using [`where` clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) (e.g. `select * from product where nama like 'pe%'` to find all `product` with "nama" started by "pe").  if you want to filter on an array, you can use php [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) (e.g. `$n = array_filter($result, function($k) { return strpos($k[nama], 'pe') !== false} ))`).

Comment: Ahhh u're right, so i just search with adding Where nama Like 'condition' . Tysm for ur help!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).